# Object Initialization Can Be Simplified for ToolStripButton - (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So I have quite a few of these warnings in my code.

```
Object Initialization Can Be Simplified
```

However from doing some Googling, I can't seem to work out how to simplify it (I'm very new to VB.NET). A lost of the stuff I've found online seems to relate to C# as well.

Below is once instance where I get the warning - relating to initializing a ToolStripButton. As far as I can tell this is fine, however is there something I'm missing?

```
Dim toolStripButton As New ToolStripButton

toolStripButton.Image = img
toolStripButton.Name = applicationName
toolStripButton.ToolTipText = applicationName
toolStripButton.CheckOnClick = True
```

Comment: Look here for the relevant syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/how-to-declare-an-object-by-using-an-object-initializer. Personally, I would just leave it the way you find it more readable, there is effectively zero difference between the two.

Comment: Press `ALT+ENTER` while the caret is on the line that gives you that information: it will *fix it* for you (it's just a preference you can change in the Code Style options of the Text Editor). In this case, it's just the use of a `With` block.

Comment: Thanks both of you! Fixed it now. The `ALT+ENTER` I didn't realize was a thing. Very good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "warning" is likely suggesting that you instantiate thusly:

```
Dim toolStripButton As [ToolStripButton =] New ToolStripButton With {
    .Image = img,
    .Name = applicationName,
    .ToolTipText = applicationName,
    .CheckOnClick = True
}
```

Purely a choice, tho I tend to adhere to this form because it's 1) more concise/less typing and 2) a bit clearer and more contained.

If you mouse-over the light bulb in the left margin ([image]) you'll see the suggestion you mention - among others - and if you mouse-over *that* you'll see code change suggestions, which you can click to apply a change.

**ASIDE**

One thing that VB-NET gives you over C# is the `With` statement which provides a similar form for multi-property classes. Eg:

```
Dim toolStripButton As [ToolStripButton =] New ToolStripButton
With toolStripButton
    .Image = img
    .Name = applicationName
    .ToolTipText = applicationName
    .CheckOnClick = True
End With
```

Comment: "and you can click on the things inside the lightbulb to have VS make the change for you on this instance/this document/this project/entire solution"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Exactly what I needed.